# Поисковая форма из XML RSS, Как предварительно выводить данные на экран и вытащить enclosure (изображение)?

Tags: php, парсер, xml, rss

Форма

```
<form method="POST" action="parser.php">
    <input type="text" name="search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Искать"/>
</form>
```

Parser.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 # Что искать
    $search = isset($_POST['search']) ? trim($_POST['search']) : null;
    
    # Если не указан текст поиска
    !empty($search) or die('Укажите, что искать');
    
    # Массив адресов RSS
    $urls = [
        'https://www.biletiavia.ru/rss.xml',
        # и т.д.
    ];
    
    # Обходим массив адресов
    foreach($urls as $url)
    {
        # Получаем данные из XML 
        $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
        
        # Сортируем массив
        usort($rss->channel->item, function($a, $b){
            # Преобразуем время
            $a = strtotime($a->pubDate);
            $b = strtotime($b->pubDate);
            
            # Если даты равны
            if($a == $b) return 0;
            
            # Сравниваем и возвращаем, выше или ниже переместить элемент
            return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
        });
        
        foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) 
        {            
            # Если не найдено совпадение
            if( !substr_count( $item->description, $search ) )
                # Переходим к следующему
                continue;
            
            # Выводим
            echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'">';
            echo '<h2>'. $item->title .'</h2>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo $item->description; 
        }
    }
?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Два вопроса.

1. Как сделать предварительный просмотр результата поиска до нажатия кнопки Найти во всплывающем окошке
2. Как вытащить ссылку на изображение

Структура XML

```
<item>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">2904385835</guid>
            <title>Подобрать выигрышную комбинацию для лотереи 4 из 20</title>
            <link>https://combinacii.ru/4_iz_20/</link>
            <author>Администратор</author>
            <category>Новости сайта</category>
            <description>4 из 20 генерирование случайных чисел с выбором числа комбинаций, генерирование комбинации это высокий шанс выиграть крупные деньги</description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<h2>Генератор комбинаций 4 чисел из 20</h2><h2>Количество комбинаций</h2><h2>4 из 20</h2><p>Лотерея 4 из 20 входит в топ самых покупаемых лотерей. Ежедневно десятки тысяч людей участвуют в розыгрышах миллионов рублей. Практически каждый месяц появляется счастливчик, сорвавший Джекпот в этой лотерее. Что-бы помочь вам стать миллионером мы создали генератор для этой лотереи, способный составить различные комбинации, некоторые из которых могут быть выигрышными.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jun 2023 18:17:26 +0300</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="http://combinacii.ru/generator_chisel.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="0" />
        </item>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Первый вопрос не понятен. Ответ на второй  вопрос смотрите по ссылке https://www.php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes